# Call PHP function using ajax in WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I want to call a php function using ajax. Here is my form code

```
    <form class="woocommerce-form woocommerce-form-login login" method="post">
    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="reg_billing_name"><?php esc_html_e( 'Full Name', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="reg_billing_name" id="reg_billing_name" autocomplete="reg_billing_name" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['reg_billing_name'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['reg_billing_name'] ) ) : ''; ?>" />
    </p>

    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="reg_billing_email"><?php esc_html_e( 'Email Address', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="email" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="reg_billing_email" id="reg_billing_email" autocomplete="reg_billing_email" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['reg_billing_email'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['reg_billing_email'] ) ) : ''; ?>" />
    </p> 

    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="reg_billing_phone"><?php esc_html_e( 'Mobile Number', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="tel" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="reg_billing_phone" id="reg_billing_phone" autocomplete="reg_billing_phone" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['reg_billing_phone'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['reg_billing_phone'] ) ) : ''; ?>" />
    </p> 
    <button type="submit" class="woocommerce-Button button" onclick="customerregister();"><?php esc_html_e( 'Register', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
    </form>

<script>
 function customerregister() {
            $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: {
                action: 'devsol_customer_auth_register'
            },
            success: function(data, status, xhr){
                console.log(data)
                if(data.data == 'success')
                    window.location = 'http://localhost/final/my-account'
                else
                    alert("Error: No account found with this Mobile number. Please register now and get 10% Discount coupon.")

            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                // this error case means that the ajax call, itself, failed, e.g., a syntax error
                // in your_function()
                alert ('Request failed: ' + thrownError.message) ;
            },
        })
     }       
</script>
```

I want to call this php function

```
function devsol_customer_auth_register() {
    $customer_name = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['reg_billing_name'] );
    $customer_phone = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['reg_billing_phone'] );
    $customer_email = sanitize_email( $_POST['reg_billing_email'] );    
    $customer_password = wp_generate_password( 12, true );       

if ( !username_exists($customer_phone) && !email_exists($customer_email) ) {       
        $user_id = wp_create_user($customer_phone, $customer_password, $customer_email);                                 
        if ( !is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {   

        wp_clear_auth_cookie();
        wp_set_current_user ( $user_id );
        wp_set_auth_cookie  ( $user_id );

        wp_update_user(array( 
            'ID' => $user_id,
            'first_name' => $customer_name,
            'role' => 'customer', ));      
        }      
    }   
    else {
        echo 'Account already existed';
    }  
}
```

How can I call php function in WordPress using ajax or javascript.

I get a error message in alert box and error is : Request failed: undefined

I added php, html and javascript ajax in my question someone please help me what i did wrong ?

Comment: @RobinZigmond Hello Sir, I have updated my question with my ajax. Please check

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately the alert doesn't tell us much of anything, other than that something went wrong with the Ajax call. Can you check in the Network section of your developer tools and see what is going on with the Ajax request: in particular the URL, the HTTP status, and the response (if any).

Answer (score 0):

Paste this code in your function.php

```php
add_action( 'wp_ajax_devsol_customer_auth_register', 'devsol_customer_auth_register' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_devsol_customer_auth_register', 'devsol_customer_auth_register' );


function devsol_customer_auth_register() {

    $customer_name = sanitize_text_field( $_REQUEST['reg_billing_name'] );
    $customer_phone = sanitize_text_field( $_REQUEST['reg_billing_phone'] );
    $customer_email = sanitize_email( $_REQUEST['reg_billing_email'] );    
    $customer_password = wp_generate_password( 12, true );       

    if ( !username_exists($customer_phone) && !email_exists($customer_email) ) {       
            $user_id = wp_create_user($customer_phone, $customer_password, $customer_email);                                 
            if ( !is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {   

            wp_clear_auth_cookie();
            wp_set_current_user ( $user_id );
            wp_set_auth_cookie  ( $user_id );

            wp_update_user(array( 
                'ID' => $user_id,
                'first_name' => $customer_name,
                'role' => 'customer', ));      
            } 
            $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
            $user->set_role( 'customer' );
            wp_mail( $customer_email, 'New User Registration', 'Your Password: ' . $customer_password );     
        }   
    else {
        echo 'Account already existed';
    } 
}
```

Thanks